# Why are some products not priced openly?

Tags: pricing

OK - maybe this is meta, so feel free to move it.

I am looking for a 100 Ohm precision calibration standard. Seems a number of companies do them but all (so far) have a "Call for price". Why? Why can't they (or their distributors) actually name a price online? I find this *extremely* annoying, especially if I do ask for a price they assume I want to be spammed by them for all eternity. This seems typical behaviour for specialist stuff.

Comment: Do we have an econ SE? Actually we do: http://economics.stackexchange.com/ You question applies to almost any low-volume specialty item. Nobody asked that question there yet, but https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/2yesuc/eli5_what_is_the_benefitpurpose_of_call_for_price/

Comment: Then why is there a "pricing" tag?

Comment: Also, the reddit answer suggests it is just a scam

Comment: Probably because *some* products will have a real price online. The price tag is likely a standard tag for all products on the site and some 'prices' are 'call for price'.

Comment: @DirkBruere: because people can freely create tags that get then reused by others. We have no formal process on tag creation.

Comment: [Price discrimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_discrimination) is not a scam.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff So, "If you seem ignorant and don't know what price you should be paying we will squeeze you for every penny" is not a scam?

Comment: No. It's not. Time is money. Or better said, information is valuable/money too. And getting information usually requires time and possibly money too; see all the [market surveys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_research) you can buy.

Comment: It certainly is if it is my time being wasted

Comment: @DirkBruere: no, that is called "the market" and happens everywhere. You could also ask "why do shops charge twice as much as online stores for the same product".

Comment: Price discrimination certainly feels like a scam when you're on the receiving end of it. But "call for price" is more about them wanting to put a sales person on the line to upsell you: it's rare that people are shopping for only one specialist item ever, more that they're a business or an institution which may want more.

Comment: It is why I will never again "call for price".

Comment: @DirkBruere: This then likely means you will never step into certain areas of technology where you won't get anything else

Comment: Or of life. Does your [prospective] SO come with a sticker price? Don't feel bad about it. A lot of people [hate negotiating](http://www.autoblog.com/2014/06/03/americans-hate-car-shopping-so-rather-give-up-sex-do-taxes/).

Comment: If they want me to haggle in some Arab Bazaar then they are out of luck. eBay, OTOH, does list prices...

"Teletek is an N.I.S.T.-traceable calibration lab which has been in business for over 30 years.  Every calibrated  item that we list on ebay has been inspected, reconditioned, calibrated and certified, and will ship with a certificate of calibration which will show the date of calibration, standards used, environmental conditions, etc., with the date of calibration within the past 30 days as of the ship date to you. "

Comment: And yes, I will check their claims via existing calibration equipment

Comment: And regarding the pricing tag: there some pricing issues that are [somewhat] particular to the EE field (see http://www.ebnonline.com/author.asp?section_id=3758) but "call for price" is surely generic enough that I don't know what could be said about it here that couldn't be said on the econ SE.

Comment: I personally agree with OP, even though this question is not about EE only. For me it seems unethical and very conservative. Its 2015, nobody wants to waste so much time to know the very basic information about the product, not to mention that in the end you could probably decide not to buy it - so they basically waste your time for free and like @Respawned Fluff said Time is money - they just took my money from me basically. It is their right to do so - but I do and advice others not even to spend a minute on the sites that do that.

Comment: This is a 100% Opinion based debate, and does not belong at all on this board.

Comment: This isn't about electronics, and is asking for opinion anyway.

Comment: I would suggest either to move this to economics SE or delete it, because probably this question is already asked, just need to find it. Not 100% opinion based in my opinion, because there is some business decision behind it. But yeah, not much electronics related, I agree.

Comment: "Please call for specifications" - would anyone tolerate that?

Comment: @DirkBruere: [Check this out](http://www.ietlabs.com/esi-sr1-0-1-standard-resistor.html)

Comment: @EMFields That's exactly what I am complaining about. I refuse to waste my time with that "call for quote BS"

Comment: @DirkBruere:  Since they **do** list the one-piece price, I'm sure that what they have in mind is an RFQ for multiple pieces. And, since they're not a DigiKey, I don't really see anything wrong with that. Of course that's just my opinion...

Comment: @EMFields Where? All I see is a big button saying "Request a quote"

Comment: @DirkBruere: when I click on the link in my comment, I see "$1552" in the same box with the red quote button in it.

Comment: @EMFields Then they must see that my IP address is UK, and call me cynical but I do not think they will be giving me a better price if I call

Comment: When I access the site using a proxy with a US IP address I see the price

Comment: Perhaps, then, some of the other sites you visited didn't publish prices for the same reason. Oh,well...